# CSV download only generating webpage html using Urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am having issues downloading a csv file with urllib2. Here is the code I am using..

```
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2
import csv

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
authentication_url = login_website
payload = {
    'altxuname': username,
    'altxpass': password,
    'Submit': 'Login'
}
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
opener.open(authentication_url, data)
resp = opener.open(csv_url)
contents = csv.reader(resp)


with open('logintest.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(contents)
    f.close()
```

I have tested the code on csv files on websites that do not require a login. I have also tested the login part and am able to login and navigate to the webpage but when I try to combine the two login and then try to download a the file all I get in the csv file is the html of the webpage. The url I am using for csv_url is a direct link to download the file. Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

**Edit**
Here is the code for the button click..

```
<input name="exportcsv" type="button" class="button"     onclick="location.href='/techforce/report.php?report_id=129&amp;rf_67=&amp;rf_31=08%2F04%2F2014&amp;rt_31=&amp;rf_448=&amp;rt_448=&amp;rf_64=&amp;rt_64=&amp;rf_387=c.state&amp;rf_387_Op=equals&amp;rf_387_Value=&amp;rf_148=c.state&amp;rf_148_Op=equals&amp;rf_148_Value=&amp;rf_223_Op=&amp;rf_55_Op=&amp;rf_46_Op=&amp;Submit=Display+Report&amp;export=csv&amp;csv=true'" value="Export CSV">
```

Comment: It depends entirely on the website how they choose to behave. What does the HTML returned tell you?

Comment: It just returns the page source.

Comment: The source of *what* page? The login page, an error page, what?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters It logs in successfully it returns the source page that the export csv button is on. The only difference between the page url and the download url is '&csv=true' which is executed on the button click

Comment: As we cannot see how the site is implemented what exactly is missing here is going to be guesswork. Perhaps the button click does a *POST* request with extra data?

Comment: I added the code for the button click does that help at all?

Comment: Right, that issues a GET request. Perhaps the page checks for the referrer? Hard to say, you'll have to guess and try out additional headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is website specific problem, no generic solution. But try using mechanize library (in Python) and you can solve this type of problem quickly. Mechanize works like a browser in your code.